# How to run a tensorflow program on an EC2 instance while staying in the free tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-ec2

I've attempted to setup an EC2 instance so I can run my `Tensorflow` script. However, I've noticed that I cannot setup the instance with a storage space of `< 75` `GiB`.

This is the error message I get...

> Launch Failed
>
> Volume of size 30GB is smaller than snapshot 'snap-030808799cdf9332b', expect size >= 75GB

Everything is within the free tier range except the storage space. It is only free tier for the storage space if it is set to `< 30` `GiB`.

I am running the following `AMI` which is free tier...

```
Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu) Version 12.0 - ami-d1c9cdae
```

My instance type is `t2.micro` which is also free tier.

Everything is free tier except for my storage space due to the space needed for my snapshot. I cannot change the snapshot so I am forced to go outside of the free tier.

Is there any work around to this? Is there anyway I can run `Tensorflow` without having to pay for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Snapshots cannot be restored to an EBS volume smaller then the snapshot. You can restore to a larger EBS volume.

Your option is to use a standard Linux AMI such as Amazon Linux 2, Ubuntu, etc. and then install Tensorflow yourself. If you are learning Tensorflow, I recommend going thru the process of installation and configuration.

Comment: This makes sense, I'm familiar with Tensorflow but have never used AWS or anything similar.